# Flutter-initialize video as quick as possible

Tags: video, flutter

I'm trying to play videos as user swipe to left or right.
I was able to play next or previous video by using `NotificationListener`.
If user swipe to left, pass next url and initialize,  if swipe right vice versa.
However with this approach, video will be initialized after user swiped.
So, it takes a couple of seconds to play.
How can I make this more efficiently?
Do I have to initialize next video while current video playing or similar?
Can someone guide me to the correct way please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it appears too broad to me. You have not provided a specific enough problem. Generaly answering your question: The way you explained it, you will have to initialize your videos beforehand.

Comment: Sorry about that but I wanted to ask not just my approach but also if there are better way, I would like to know. Or am I the right way to achieve this functionality. Anyway that might be too broad I'll be careful next time sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the video widget using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html
to initialize it before it is shown to the user.

Comment: link expire....